# How can I create a function prototype in C++ which accepts two integers as parameters and returns their difference?

Tags: c++

I know what a function is and how to create it, but what is a function prototype? And how can I create a function prototype in C++ which accepts two integers as parameters and returns their difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function prototype:

```
int difference(int,int);
```

function definition:

```
int difference(int a,int b)
{
 return abs(a-b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A function prototype in C++ is simply a function declaration. So in your case it could be

```
 int difference(int n1, int n2);
```